# Xamarin Insights Portal: I only see Issues and Settings tabs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.insights

When i open Insights portal, i only see these tabs:

[image]

i don't see Users, Audience and Events tab as in xamarin guide:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Insights subscription tier determines which features *(tabs)* are available.  I'm going to guess that yours is "Insights Basic", which only includes `Issues` and `Settings`.  If you were to upgrade your tier *(which I'm not sure you can anymore due to the MS merge and migration to HockeyApp)* you would see all of the tabs, matching the guide.  If you really need the features, you should email Xamarin support.

*Old Xamarin Insights tier page via web.archive.org (https://web.archive.org/web/20160304014709/http://xamarin.com/insights#pricing)* [image: old insights pricing]